# casting to the same type

Tags: c++, c++11, static-cast

I have this case:

```
using T = classA; //T could be classA and could be `classB` in other platforms.
T a;
auto x = static_cast<classB>(a);
```

In case that T is `classA` the casting is must. In case of T is `classB` the casting is redundant.

By standard, would the second casting be dropped (no more executable code) since it is not necessary?

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26858851/391161), it is not clear what you mean by `dropped`.

Comment: If by dropped you mean that it results in no executable code, than yes. Based on the answer **merlin** linked to.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I meant. Thanks

Comment: not sure what you mean by "In case that T is long int the casting is must" either.  `long b = 5; int x = b;` is fine

Comment: @M.M my fault. the example I wrote was not so helpful. They are actually user-defined classes rather than just int and long

Comment: In that case the static_cast may generate assembly instructions even if it is to the same type

Comment: @m.m I see So a compile time check would be a nice performance enhancement here

Comment: how about `classB x = a;`

Comment: @M.M AAA rule has mislead me again. Definitely correct and elegant. Thanks

Comment: The standard does not say how many assembly instructions will be generated. If you care, then measure.

Comment: N3690: 5.2.9/4: *An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T using a static_cast of the form `static_cast<T>(e)`
if the declaration `T t(e);` is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5). **The effect of such an
explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary
variable** as the result of the conversion. The expression e is used as a glvalue if and only if the initialization
uses it as a glvalue.* --------- From this point, it seems that such `static_cast` will put us on compiler's (optimization) mercy.

Comment: @iammilind - *An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T using a static_cast of the form static_cast<T>(e) if the declaration T t(e); is well-formed, **for some invented temporary variable t**. The effect of such an explicit conversion is the same as performing the declaration and initialization and then using the temporary variable as the result of the conversion.* **I just need to ask: If `static_cast<T>(e)` is well-formed, Does the temporary `t` is *really* created and then initialized from `e`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the C++11 Standard:

> **5.2.9 Static cast**
>
> 1 The result of the expression `static_cast<T>(v)` is the result of converting the expression `v` to type `T`.

When the type of `v` is the same as `T`, the conversion is simple when `T` is not a class. A decent compiler *should not* generate any executable code for such usages of `static_cast`.

Comment: I think this is wrong, the `static_cast` should call the copy-constructor. [Example](https://godbolt.org/g/ni7n55). see 5.2.9/4 (in C++14)

Comment: Then why in @M.M, example, the copy constructor is called ?

Comment: This [one](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g6,options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B14',source:'struct+S%0A%7B%0A+++S(S+const+%26)+%7B+%7D%0A++S()%7B%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++S+s%3B%0A++static_cast%3CS%3E(s)%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3)

Comment: @RSahu http://ideone.com/PLt54x - Does not compile due to deleted copy constructor for `static_cast`.

Comment: In [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast) the first paragraph, in explanation, states : "static_cast<new_type>(expression) returns the imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type Temp(expression);"

Comment: @Pumkko - *In cppreference the first paragraph, in explanation, states : "static_cast<new_type>(expression) returns the imaginary variable Temp initialized as if by new_type Temp(expression);"* Does this mean the `Temp` object is ***really*** created?